# Infos on three nines availability

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, oracle

I'm going to develop high-available WCF service that should serving client with 99.9% uptime. As you probably guess I need as more information as possible. 
So I know here, on stackoverflow, a lot of professionals helping newbies like me :) So it would be so good for me if you point me at good experience on making .NET WCF services. 
This service will work with a lot of geographically remoted databases and will provide clients data from them.
Any articles, links, blog/forum posts and personal memories will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Three 9 availability by a newbie. Who is your boss? I need to kick him.

Comment: The more specific your question, the better results you'll get. As it is, this question is too broad.

Comment: 3x9 is not high available per definition.

Comment: perhaps he means 3x9 behind the decimal point ?

Comment: @HasanKhan Honestly, that wasn't boss requirement. This is my essential wish to make project that way. My ambitions. Of course, my boss meant that I need to release such a service, but with such requirement. It just will be a good advantage for me :)

Comment: Grab a copy of "Learning WCF" from Oreilly.  This is a very good primer.  Then get "Programming WCF Services", also Oreilly.  You already have the 2 most important things imo (desire to learn and a project!).  As a newbie, I hope this will be an internal service, you can learn while only pissing off your coworkers ;) just kidding...sort of.

Comment: @tbone Thanks! As I surprised when I found "Programming WCF Services" on my desk! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not one relevant aspect but several... just some points to consider/keep in mind:

- Redundancy
  Be it multiple machines running the service in parallel, be it some DNS-based mechanism to help when one machine is down/not reachable... be it different physical locations (Data centers) for the different machines, be it different Backbone connections (ISP)... be it a redundant DB backend (like an Oracle RAC setup) etc.
- Security
  This must be part of your design from the beginning... you need strong security in the service itself (basic things like checkng all incoming data thoroughly aside) and the runtime environment (like firewalls etc.)
- Backup
  This part must be well thought through and tested to the fullest extent... there are different technologies which differ for example in how fast you are back up and running etc. - sometimes you need to combine multilple techniques... again: test your worstcase scenario
- Monitoring
  To be sure what goes on and to react as early as possible you need a good monitoring implementation... this starts from the iron upwards and end inside the service... it should no only check availability but also things like load etc. and configurable alarming... it need to allow for history too... which in turn gives you enough data to know when are the peak hours and/or when to add new machines etc.
- Testing
  Check your service with any tool available really hard... be it a memory profiler, be it load testing with realisitc scenarios, even with extreme ones...
- Scalability
  Stateless services usually are better in terms of scalability...
- Plans
  Very important and usually forgotten or not up2date in my experience... make plans for deployment, rollout/updates, desaster recovery etc. AND most important: test them thoroughly and document them!

Comment: Excellent description. Thanks! I would be just happy if you give me some story about real implementation of this principles.

Comment: you are welcome - specific details of implementation differ from customer to customer depending on the requirements/budgets etc. and not all details are "disclosable" (because most customers demand the project details being confidential) - what do you mean by story ? what specific aspect do you need ?

Comment: My main troubles are about keeping all DB connections alive. I'm really looking to some advices in this area of attention.

Comment: This qualifies for a new question... please create a new question on SO and be as specific as possible (if you want you can put in a link to this question for context)... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having multiple servers behind a load-balancer.

Also, you may need another geographically removed remote location to ensure that kind of uptime.

Answer (score -1):

> high-available WCF service that should serving client with 99.9% uptime

Hahahhaahaha. Seriously.

99.9 is "normal computer in a rack", not "high vailable". Make your math, please. 99.9% availability is 3.65 days per year downtime. I would call a normal computer crappy if you have that - including repairs.

This level of availability is "buy a server from dell with a technician on site within 24 hours in case something fails".

Comment: We have all necessary hardware inc. servers for that purpose :)

Comment: That is ONE server. You think 99.9 is "good". it SUCKS. It is worse than what you get with a normal comptuer you buy in a shop.

Comment: Ehh, I think 0.1% of a year is 0.365 days.

Comment: @TomTom Tell us about this your enlightening experience :)